# Loading a Cube from a DataWarehouse using SQL

Tags: sql, database, cube

New to this and need your help on this issue. Seems to be a simple one.

So I am trying to load the fact data into my Cognos Transformer cube. But before doing that I need to build the SQL.
So to give a simple example, I have a fact table that has Foreignkeys from 8 dimensions and a single measure. 
What I need is to build is a SQL that loads the data for 4 dimensions and the Measure. 
So here is the fact table - 
    **Fact_Table (SK, FDim1, FDim2 , FDim3 ,FDim4 ,FDim5 ,FDim6 ,FDim7 ,FDim8 , Quantity)**

Can you please guide me if the below simple query is the way to go ?

```
select Dim1.Col1, Dim2.Col1, Dim3.Col1, Dim4.Col1, Fact_Table.Quantity
from 
Fact_Table F
left join Dim1 A ON A.KeyDim1 =  F.FDim1
left join Dim2 B ON A.KeyDim2 =  F.FDim2
left join Dim3 C ON A.KeyDim3 =  F.FDim3
left join Dim4 D ON A.KeyDim4 =  F.FDim4
```

I have not used groupby as I need to load the data at the detail level and let the cube aggregate it.
I believe I am missing something and wanted the Gurus here to guide me:)
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use groupby, because you are changing level of detalization (8 measures to 4), so you should groupby selected data by this 4 measures and summarize quantity

Comment: Thanks Viktor :) Can you also guide me if the joins I am using are the correct ones ? So all left outer joins ?

Comment: Well, it's better to use left joins, because your fact table may consists null values in dimensions fields. It's not good, but it can be. You could read here for example http://www.kimballgroup.com/2010/10/design-tip-128-selecting-default-values-for-nulls/ or here http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/02/design-tip-43-dealing-with-nulls-in-the-dimensional-model/